# When does ONNX decide to include a Gather op?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, onnx-coreml

Obscure question, I suppose, but I have a PyTorch model that I've just built, and it's failing to convert to CoreML because ONNX has added `Gather` ops. The complete model is actually an amalgamation of two separate models, intended to improve performance by keeping the processing on the GPU/Metal for as long as possible.

Building this "composite" model required me to create a couple of slices, of the form `x = y[:, 0]`, and I'm wondering if these might be the reason for the `Gather` ops?

I do realize I can create a custom layer, but I've just been through a horrible fiasco with custom layers in CoreML, that wasted many, many hours, and got me nowhere, so I'm trying to find another way around the problem.

If finding a way around those slices would prevent ONNX from adding `Gather` I'd be willing to search for a solution.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Answering my own question, it seems that slices do lead to Gather ops in ONNX. They also appear to come from `cat` and `stack` calls. Honestly, I wish PyTorch would just write their own mlmodel export utility (I understand there is something in early stages)—trying to build something that makes the journey from PyTorch to ONNX to CoreML is an exercise in profound aggravation...